# What exactly is a subkey?

Tags: gnupg, pgp, key-generation, openpgp

I fairly understand the math behind RSA, Elgamal, AES, SHA but not how things are used in practise. How are subkeys different from master key? I understand its purpose from various websites but How is it internally implemented? How is it bound to the master key? Is it an OpenPGP terminology?

Comment: This helped me a lot: https://wiki.debian.org/Subkeys

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This [post by user rjh from 2008 in the enigmail forum](https://www.enigmail.net/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=375) answers it well:

> Originally in PGP 2.6, back in the early 90s, you had just one keypair
>   and it was used for both encryption and signing. The ability to have
>   additional keypairs presented some engineering challenges. Ultimately,
>   it was decided that the additonal keypairs would be called "subkeys",
>   despite the fact there's nothing "sub" about them. Likewise, what you
>   call your "key" isn't really a key at all--the terminology is a
>   holdover from the days when a key really was a key. Nowadays, a key is
>   really a *collection* of keys, along with some metadata for user
>   identifiers, signatures, etc.
>
> E.g., my "key" has four keypairs on it: 5B8709EB, D0C6AAE4, 71E177DB
>   and 8DB02BBB3.
>
> What GnuPG calls your "public key" is really the oldest signing key in
>   the collection. E.g., since 5B8709EB was created first, GnuPG calls
>   the entire set of keys and metadata the "5B8709EB key".
>
> So, "is it possible to have a key that's used for encryption and
>   signing without any subkey at all?" The answer here is no, because
>   *all* keypairs on a key are subkeys. Even if there's only one of them.

Answer (score 18):

### Subkeys

Subkey packets are defined in [RFC 4880, OpenPGP, 5.5 Key Material Packet](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#section-5.5). They're only distinguished by another packet ID, and require a binding signature to be actually useful (see below).

> A Public-Subkey packet (tag 14) has exactly the same format as a
> Public-Key packet, but denotes a subkey.

### Subkey Usage

OpenPGP subkeys are used for different purposes:

- Being able to store the primary key offline or a more secure device. If a machine with a subkey is harmed, you can easily revoke the subkey without all the hassles of revoking your primary key (sharing a new key, getting new signatures, ...).
- Having different subkeys on different machines, for example a signing subkey on a build server. Again, revoking single keys is easy.
- Using a larger primary key for long lifetime, and shorter, but faster subkeys for day-to-day usage.
- Some algorithms do not support both encrypting and signing. For example, a DSA primary key requires another key for encryption, typically paired with ElGamal.

### Binding Signatures

There are special signature subtypes to bind subkeys to primary keys (and vice verse), listed in [RFC 4880, OpenPGP, 5.2.1 Signature Types](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#section-5.2.1):

> #### 0x18: Subkey Binding Signature
>
> This signature is a statement by the top-level signing key that
> indicates that it owns the subkey.  This signature is calculated
> directly on the primary key and subkey, and not on any User ID or
> other packets.  A signature that binds a signing subkey MUST have
> an Embedded Signature subpacket in this binding signature that
> contains a 0x19 signature made by the signing subkey on the
> primary key and subkey.
>
> #### 0x19: Primary Key Binding Signature
>
> This signature is a statement by a signing subkey, indicating
> that it is owned by the primary key and subkey.  This signature
> is calculated the same way as a 0x18 signature: directly on the
> primary key and subkey, and not on any User ID or other packets.

Comment: Also section 12.1 of RFC 4880 has a schema that explains the format of keys. And section 15 mentions that "The 0x19 back signatures were not required for signing subkeys until relatively recently."