# Generate and add new encryption subkey?

Tags: gnupg, key-generation, key

My encryption [subkey](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/108930/29728) (but not my signing or other [subkey](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/108930/29728)s) expired. How do I generate and add a new encryption [subkey](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/108930/29728) using `gpg`?

Comment: Are you sure you want to generate a new subkey and not extend the key's expiration date?

Comment: @MichaelAltfield : good question. What's the best strategy between both options ? I asked the question (https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/274364/pgp-expired-encryption-subkey-renew-or-replace)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
gpg --edit-key <KEY_ID> addkey
```

Choose

```
   (5) Elgamal (encrypt only)
   (6) RSA (encrypt only)
```

<sup>source: gpg manpage</sup>