# PGP expired encryption subkey : renew or replace?

Tags: gnupg, pgp, key, expiration-date

I am in the process of learning PGP (GnuPG more precisely).

I am trying to figure out which is the best strategy for my encryption (`[E]`) subkey in terms of expiration/revocation/renewal. Could you please tell me if the following affirmations are correct ? Because I am not sure I understand everything correctly :

- Strategy 1 (by default with GnuPG) : an `[E]` subkey without expiration date.

  - Advantage : the most easy setup to administrate, nothing to do
  - If the private `[E]` subkey is compromised (but not the master key), I can always revoke that subkey.
  - Caveats : I have no influence on how often other users update my public key. If some users don't update it for a long time, they won't know it has been revoked, and thus they may still use it to encrypt messages, although it has been compromised
- Strategy 2 : set an expiration date on the `[E]` subkey. In that case, what should I do when the subkey expires ? I have the choice between extending the expiration date of the existing subkey, or issue a brand new `[E]` subkey :

  - Extending the existing subkey's expiration date can present some risk, in case that subkey has been compromised without my knowledge. An attacker could keep using it to decrypt new messages, without my or my correspondents knowledge
  - Issuing a new subkey cancels that risk (the attacker would have to gain access to the new subkey to decrypt future messages)
  - From the other users point of view, there's no difference between the 2 options (extending the expiration date or issuing a new key), because in each case they will have to update my public key because of expiration.

So, in conclusion :

- Easiest thing to do is to issue an `[E]` subkey without expiration date, but it's the less secure strategy
- A more secure strategy would be to periodically issue a new `[E`] subkey every *n* years
- Extending an existing `[E]` subkey's expiration date doesn't really make any sense : it's less secure than issuing a new subkey, and requires the same work from the part of my correspondents (in both case they have to update my public key)

What do you think ? I am not the only one asking that question, but I couldn't find a thorough answer (see [Generate and add new encryption subkey?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/147950/generate-and-add-new-encryption-subkey/#comment479220_147950) or https://www.reddit.com/r/GnuPG/comments/dma9hp/expired_encryption_subkey_renew_or_replace/)

Comment: You almost certainly want to extend your key. Your contacts will be pretty annoyed with you if they have a ton of distinct keys from you in their keyrings.

Comment: We are talking about subkeys here, not distinct keys. If there's only one valid (e.g., non expired) encryption subkey, I don't see how my contacts could be annoyed. Encryption software will automatically select the valid subkey.